# Change background color of label Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to change the background color of labels in a Polar Chart. I want to change the background color to black.

I'm using the global variable to change the font color:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)';
```

This is the chart that is shown.

[Chart Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdhxU.png)

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [25, 10, 20],
            backgroundColor: [
                'yellow',
                'blue',
                'red',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'yellow',
                'blue',
                'red',
            ],
        }],
        labels: [
            'Yellow',
             'Blue',
             'Red',
        ]
    },
    type: 'polarArea',
});
```

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the official documentation, and they seemed to have the same issue, especially when changing the theme to 'Night' or 'Sepia' from 'White'.

[image: Example]

However, under further inspection, I found [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3864) GitHub issue that explained it.

After `type: 'polarArea',` add the following code to change the background-color of the text elements:

```
options: {
        scale: {
            ticks: {
              backdropColor: 'black'
            }
        }
    }
```

There is also a JSFiddle I made, which is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/username3953/7m5ycojw/27/). Also, in [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5573) GitHub issue, I found that docs for this is under Linear Radial Axis, *not* in Polar Area. Hope that helps!

Comment: This saved me many hours of web search, thanks